# Is ColumnDataSource() the only way to get plots updated in a bokeh web app?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, callback, bokeh

My data is in a large multi-indexed pandas `DataFrame`. I re-index to flatten the `DataFrame` and then feed it through `ColumnDataSource`, but I need to group my data row wise in order to plot it correctly (think bunch of torque curves corresponding to a bunch of gears for a car). If I just plot the dictionary output of `ColumnDataSource`, it's a mess.

I've tried converting the `ColumnDataSource` output back to `DataFrame`, but then I lose the update functionality, the callback won't touch the `DataFrame`, and the plots won't change. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to the question in the title is "Yes". The `ColumnDataSource` is the special, central data structure of Bokeh. It provides the data for all the glyphs in a plot, or content in data tables, and automatically keeps that data synchronized on the Python and JavaScript sides, so that you don't have to, e.g write a bunch of low-level websocket code yourself. To update things like glyphs in a plot, you update the CDS that drives them.

It's possible there are improvements that could be made in your approach to updating the CDS, but it is impossibe to speculate without seeing actual code for what you have tried.

Comment: Thank you bigreddot! I have since figured out a workaround using CDSView which allows row-wise filtering.